# Ionic + ngCordova(ImagePicker) not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Have no idea what im doing wrong, can you please help me with the code?
Cordova 6.2.0
Ionic 1.7.15 

ng-click="getImages()" the cellphone closes the application , debugging on google "chrome://inspect/#devices" the application stop at line 940(cordova.js):

```
var msgs = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(bridgeSecret, service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

App:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope ,$cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPlatform)
```

```
$scope.getImages = function() {


$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    var options = {
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        quality: 80
    };

    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('error');
    });

});

};
```

Comment: Does the app has the permission to access images on device?

Comment: was missing u.u, permissions....